# Is there a way to change the following VBScript into javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, vbscript

I'm attempting to convert some VBScript to javascript, but I doubt it's possible because it seems to be specific to MS apps and code. I'd like help with either of the two possible outcomes: a) actually converting the code to javascript, or b) demonstrating that converting it to javascript is currently not possible.

The specific VBScript statements that I consider too MS-specific are:

```
set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
oBook.HTMLProject.HTMLProjectItems("Sheet1").Text = sHTML
oBook.HTMLProject.RefreshDocument()
oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.UserControl = True
```

Has anyone interfaced javascript and Excel well enough for a solution to exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure like this:-

```
 var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
 var book = excel.Workbooks.Add()

 //The line below doesn't work in Excel 2007
 // book.HTMLProject.HTMLProjectItems["Sheet1"].Text = sHtml

 var sheet =  book.Sheets("Sheet1")
 sheet.Range("A2").Value = "Hello World"
 excel.Visible = true
 excel.UserControl = true
```

Comment: This code worked like a charm! After fixing a minor typo from the non-quoted code (OuterHTML != outerHTML in javascript), everything is just as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only with JScript, not JavaScript- [this will show you how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394616(VS.85).aspx). This may be fine if you are using only IE.